# How to combine two select query with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I know that `union` can be done to combine two queries if they have same number and type of columns. But I've a condition where I've to combine two select statement with different tables and different columns though 1 table is common in both i.e. *PatientAppointment*. Here are the two statements:

```
select p.CDRId, p.Gender,p.MRN,p.DoB as DOB,pa.AppointmentDateTime,cn.Description,ehv.ProgramName,
 cn.CreatedBy as CareTeamStaffMember,cn.Profile as Role,cn.Title as Credentials,
 date_format(pa.AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m') BillingMonth,
 ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
(case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes
from Patient p inner join EnrollmentHistoryView ehv on ehv.CDRId = p.CDRId
inner join ClinicalNote cn on cn.CDRId = p.CDRId
inner join PatientAppointment pa on pa.CDRId = p.CDRId 
where p.CDRId='9493b505-03b9-46a0-b009-99b34f7a5d41' 
and ehv.ProgramName!='N/A'
group by p.CDRId, p.Gender, p.MRN, p.Dob, pa.AppointmentDateTime,cn.Description,cn.CreatedBy,cn.Profile,cn.Title,pa.Duration,ehv.ProgramName
```

UNION

```
SELECT AppointmentDateTime,
       duration,
       minutes,
       CASE WHEN @prev_month != BillingMonth
            THEN total >= 20
            WHEN @prev_total < 20 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END 99457Elig,
       CASE WHEN @prev_month != BillingMonth
            THEN total >= 40
            WHEN @prev_total < 40
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END 99458Elig,
       @prev_month := BillingMonth BillingMonth,
       @prev_total := total total
FROM (select AppointmentDateTime,
             duration,
             @cur_dur := ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
                         (case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes,

             CASE WHEN @year_month = date_format(AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN @cum_sum := @cum_sum + @cur_dur
                  ELSE @cum_sum := @cur_dur
                  END total,
             @year_month := date_format(AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m') BillingMonth

      from PatientAppointment, (SELECT @year_month:='', @cum_sum:=0, @cur_dur:=0) variables
      ORDER BY AppointmentDateTime) subquery,
(SELECT @prev_month:=0, @prev_total:=0) variable
ORDER BY AppointmentDateTime
```

The query is too complex and I can't create the data set also. Please help me with the approach. Give me some suggestion at least. I'll try it myself.

Comment: I think you want to get additional patient info from another query. And you want those columns to be added in the records of first query. You should do that in programming language like `php` whatever you're using. If you still want to use in `mysql` try join on these two queries considering them temporary tables generated from subquery.

Comment: So it would be like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ) as a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2) as b ON a.some_attr = b.another_attr`

Comment: @JitendraYadav, I understand what you're saying. But still getting errors. We're in same time zone can we take this on skype please? I'm stuck with this since 5 days. :-(

Comment: I can share my screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your first query as `Query1` and second query as `Query2`, you can use simple join between these two.

As you said `PatientAppointment` table is common in both, use its primary key(`CDRId`) as joining between these two. So your query would look like.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( Query1 ) AS table1
INNER JOIN ( Query2) AS table2 ON table1.CDRId = table2.CDRId;
```

Comment: Hi Jitendra. I'm facing a new issue now. Can we have a qucik discussion please.

Comment: @Tanzeel, for another issue, please create a separate question. You may get prompt help from other guys too.

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025684/how-to-use-group-by-in-a-query-while-using-variables